# Fluent UI React Combo and DropDown not opening in CRA app

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I have a new React app (CRA), with FluentUI React added to the project. Some of the FluentUI components are working fine, but neither the combo nor the dropdown are working correctly. When I click either of them to show the list of options, it does not appear. I can choose a new item using the keyboard (e.g. down key and Enter), and I can see the html being rendered into the DOM when I click the control to open it, but it's just not appearing visibly on the page anywhere.

The app is pretty simple at this point (nothing with a higher z-index, for instance). Any suggestions?

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have the same issue.